# What kind of file format is this, tab separated with ="" around fields and a header

Tags: excel, file, format, file-type, file-type-associations

I have a file of unknown type, and I need to either use some existing C# library to parse it, or write my own.

The file opens in excel but gives a "The file format and extension of filename.xxx don't match." warning.

It looks similar to a tab separated file, but has ="" around each field

[Screenshot of the file showing all symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9j1A.png)

```
="Output Date"  ="2019/08/22 10:06:14"
="Search Condition" ="Latest"
="Description"  ="123ABC"
="Description Code" =""

="Donotuse" ="Description Code" ="Col1" ="Col2"
="" ="A-Description-Here"   ="A description here"   ="AA"
="" ="Some-text"    ="Some text"    ="BB"
="" ="Some-text"    ="Some text"    ="AB"
```

I want to know what file format this is, and if there is any existing way of parsing it without having to write entirely new code for it.

Comment: Where is the file coming from, and does it have a file extension?

Comment: The file is coming from a custom developed system from a parent company. It has a .xls file extension to force excel to open it, but does not appear to be an actual excel 95, 97, 2003, etc... formatted file

Comment: The file will open in excel if you import it as a tab-delimited text file.  Looks like some kind of hack to avoid having to create an actual Excel file; a bit like the old "download an HTML table with an xls extension" which used to be used by web-based applications.  **If** none of your field values will contain tabs it would be pretty straightforward to parse though - just split on newline and then on tab.